# Sharing options below question wrap to a new line since the addition of Google+

Tags: bug, status-norepro, sharing

[image]

"Facebook" appears on a new line, which is a bit unattractive and takes up more space than it needs to. This could be fixed by rewriting the sentence:

> Know someone who can answer? [Share this question](http://example.com) via [email](http://example.com), [Google+](http://example.com), [Twitter](http://example.com), or [Facebook](http://example.com)

Comment: Just as a note the "not the answer you were looking for" already does this, though I agree the sentence can be revised

Comment: The wrapping isn't the case for me, Chrome on Windows...what OS/browser are you on?

Comment: Wraps for me in Chrome on Mac. Probably down to differing antialiasing between platforms. It's something that can be infuriating to get right on every device and screen.